# How to get notified of a new lead in SalesForce?

Tags: salesforce, webhooks

I want to get notified when a new lead is created in Salesforce. Is there something like webhook in Salesforce or some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, plenty of options :)

For Salesforce as actor:

1. Workflow rule that would fire on insert of Lead and send you an email (or if it's for system integration - [outbound message](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=workflow_defining_outbound_messages.htm)).
2. You can always write an "after insert" Apex trigger and have in it a callout to external system (SOAP and RESTful APIs are supported). Although you'll need a [@future annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm) because the triggers by default aren't supposed to send callouts (the database commit/rollback shouldn't depend on whether the external system has accepted the message or not).

For external system as actor:

1. Simply poll every once in a while for something like `[SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate > :lastTimeIhaveChecked]`
2. Or there's fairly recent addition called [Streaming API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/index.htm). Basically you define a PushTopic (query that interests you). Salesforce peeks at the current results returned by it and whenever the results change you'll get a notification. I haven't played with it yet but seems from the docs you can set event type to show "created" events only. **This might be closest to a webhook**.

Comment: Thanks eyescream, let me try Streaming API because my purpose is to integrate with external system and its much closest to webhook

Comment: This usually involves writing your own code to "subscribe to" events, construct a message and send it to an external endpoint. I have written quite extensively on this topic here: http://beachmonks.com/posts/integrations/salesforce/practical-guide.html. The source code is at: https://github.com/beachmonks/choir-salesforce

Comment: @AlexDong - feel free to post is as another answer, it's worthy of few upvotes!

Comment: Have a look at ProcessBuilder for a declarative approach. There is also a 'notification' capability now: https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/06/send-custom-notifications.html

Answer (score 12):

I hate to self-promote but since some might fine this as a useful answer...  I built a [Webhook creator for Salesforce](http://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/30/create-webhooks-on-salesforce-com).  It is open source: https://github.com/jamesward/salesforce-webhook-creator

Comment: First link points to this thread, second link points to a scala app with no readme.  Is the first link incorrect?

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to get one of these webhooks working so that when our sales guys convert a lead to a contact, we get a post with the old lead id and the new contact id?

Comment: I think this might be possible but some testing would have to be done.  And maybe a settings tweak.  It seems that the `Enable Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert` option might need to be selected: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_leadsettings.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

This usually involves writing your own code to "subscribe to" events, construct a message and send it to an external endpoint. I have written quite extensively on this topic at: http://beachmonks.com/posts/integrations/salesforce/practical-guide.html. The source code is at: http://github.com/beachmonks/choir-salesforce.

Comment: The links for your answer are broken.  Can you fix?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does support webhooks, but they are just called by a different name - **Callouts**.

Here's a link to the Developer documentation on the topic:

[Invoking Callouts Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm)

Here's a description of the feature taken directly from the link above:

> An Apex callout enables you to tightly integrate your Apex with an external service by **making a call to an external Web service or sending a HTTP request** from Apex code and then receiving the response. Apex provides integration with Web services that utilize SOAP and WSDL, or HTTP services (RESTful services).

(emphasis added)

This is basically a webhook, commonly defined as "a user-defined callback over HTTP" [2](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/webhooks/)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Use RoundRobin logic to assign new incoming leads. Then create a new WF rule to send notification to new owners plus Admin or who ever else wanted to be notified.