# How to add the CallOptions header using the salesforce REST API in PHP

Tags: php, rest, http-headers, salesforce

I am using the REST api to sync data from my wordpress site to salesforce.
I am looking to see in a report from where the api calls are originating and i found that i can use the client id in the "CallOptions" header.

My reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_calloptions.html

from that page:

```
Field name
    Sforce-Call-Options

Field values
    client—A string that identifies a client.
    defaultNamespace—A string that identifies a developer ...
```

My question is, how do i write the headers array (correct syntax) to contain the call options header with only "client" with a value.

i tried `'headers' => array('Sforce-Call-Options' => 'My-Client-Name')`
But the client id doesn't show in the report.
Also, is there maybe something i need to do in the salesforce environment because this is REST? i managed to add this in SOAP (using "setCallOptions" method)

Comment: Do you have find a solution ? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

The "Sforce-Call-Options" header is a comma delimited string, where each item in the string is a key value pair separated by equals.

```
Sforce-Call-Options: client=SampleCaseSensitiveToken/100, defaultNamespace=battle
```

If you're doing this in PHP, then you can reference this previous post.[Salesforce callout using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698402/salesforce-callout-using-php)

Comment: Inside the 'headers' array i tried:
'Sforce-Call-Options' => 'client=Shop-Sync'
and
'Sforce-Call-Options:client=Shop-Sync'
both didn't work (i didn't see the client name in the report)
Is there anything i maybe need to add inside salesforce to make use of this header?

Comment: @RealGigex I have the same problem on the report I don't see the client name